# Sharepoint 2007 - read custom page field from webpart

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts, field

How do I programatically read a custom page field from within a webpart (from the page the webpart is on)?

Thanks

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as you would a non-custom field type:

```
CustomFieldType customField = (CustomFieldType)page.ListItem["FieldName"];
```

Only you cast to your custom field type.